# SSLsample in NSS

Tags: ssl, nss

Since the latest version of NSS does not provide the SSLSample program, I copied the folder SSLSample from the older version of NSS (3.9, 3.12) to the /security/nss/cmd folder inside nss-3.12.4 .

When I run make nss_build_all in my 3.12.4, the other programs generated its own binary but not my SSLSample folder.

I would like to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add SSLSample to the DIRS list found in mozilla\security\nss\cmd\manifest.mn